# this.shadowRoot from inside a decorator

Tags: typescript

Most of my event handlers in my custom HTMLElements look like this,

```
  totalChanged() {
    if (!this.shadowRoot) return
    const t = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('#total')
    if (t) t.innerHTML = String(this.price * this.quantity)
  }
```

Is it possible to make it look something like

```
  @event('#total')
  totalChanged() {
    return String(this.price * this.quantity)
  }
```

Don't know how to get to the shadowRoot in a decorator, `this` refers to the decorator module itself, not the HTMLElement. And proto is the prototype of my custom element, also not the `this` I want.

```
export function event(select: string) {
  return (proto: any, propName: string) : any => {
    console.log(this.shadowRoot)
  }
}
```

Here `this` is just undefined

```
export function event(select: string) {
  return function (proto: any, propName: string) : any {
    console.log(this.shadowRoot)
  }
}
```

EDIT: Example

index.html

```
<test-2></test-2>
<script src="test2.js"></script>
```

test2.ts => test2.js (target ES2017)

```
function defineClass(tagname: string) {
  return function classDecorator<T extends {new(...args:any[]):{}}>(constructor:T) {
    console.log("Define: " + constructor.name)
    window.customElements.define(tagname, constructor)
    return class extends constructor {
      newProperty = "decorator";
      hello = "decorator";
    }
  }
}

function myevent(select: string) {
  return function (this:any, proto: any, propName: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) : any {
    let originalMethod = descriptor.value;
    descriptor.value = function(this:any, ...args: any[]) {
      console.log('test', this)
      return originalMethod.apply(this, args) 
    }
    return descriptor;
  }
}

@defineClass('test-2')
class Greeter2 extends HTMLElement{
  property = 'property2'
  hello = 'hello2'
  constructor() {
    super()
    console.log(this.hello)
  }
  @myevent('hello')
  helloFn() {}
  connectedCallback() { }
  disconnectedCallback() { }
  attributeChangedCallback(name: string, oldValue: string, newValue: string) { }
  adoptedCallback() { }
}
console.log('test-2: ', document.querySelector('test-2').hello)

@defineClass('test-3')
class Greeter3 {
  property = 'property3'
  hello = 'hello3'
  constructor() {
    console.log(this.hello)
  }
  @myevent('hello')
  helloFn(){}
}
console.log('test-3: ', new Greeter3());
```

EDIT2: needed to call the method `new Greeter3().helloFn()` see Diullei answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is missing the `descriptor` argument to access the object context. Try this code:

```
export function event(select: string) {
    return function (proto: any, propName: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) : any {
        let originalMethod = descriptor.value; // saving the original function

        descriptor.value = function(...args: any[]) { // changing the original function body
            console.log(this.shadowRoot);
            return originalMethod.apply(this, args); // calling original function
        }
        return descriptor;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, I added a example because I am still doing something wrong I think. The `console.log('test', this)` from myevent decorator does not get called in chrome? Dont know why?

Comment: Your code is working to me. I changed the `new Greeter3()` to `new Greeter3().helloFn()` to invoke the decorated function and the `console.log('test', this)` worked fine. Take a look if you are really calling the `helloFn()` function.

Comment: Doh! XD You are right, I assumed it was called automatically by the constructor, thanks